# Отображение элемента при клике JS & CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы **при клике или пока стоит фокус** на кнопке **'a'** , он раскрывал **input** я его скрыл , вот мой кусок кода HTML:

```
<a class="link-secondary" href="#" aria-label="search">
     <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
</a>
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.." hidden>
```

Вот мой JS, где я меняю значение **hidden** на false:

```
const searchBtn = document.querySelector('.left-menu a[aria-label=search]'),
  searchInp = document.querySelector('.left-menu input[type=text]');
    
searchBtn.addEventListener('focus', () => {
searchInp.hidden = false;
```

});

Теперь как сделать так, чтобы значение hidden возвращалось для сворачивания **input**?
Если можно в CSS , то пжлста подскажите

Comment: при каких действиях/обстоятельствах инпут должен свернутся обратно? Что нужно сделать или не сделать пользователю?

Comment: @Макск когда фокус уходит от кнопки

Comment: типа раскрывать только тогда когда я ищу что-то, а потом сворачиваться ,если ничего искать не надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного подправил ваш JS чтобы пример отобразился тут.

1. Чтобы инпут появлялся и ищезал по клику, можно сделать так

```
searchInp.hidden = !searchInp.hidden;
```

. Чтобы скрывать инпут, после ухода фокуса с него, можно использовать событие "focusout", как-то так:

```
searchInp.addEventListener('focusout', () => {
searchInp.hidden = true;
})
```

Итого:

```js
const searchBtn = document.querySelector('a[aria-label=search]'),
searchInp = document.querySelector('input[type=text]');
    
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
searchInp.hidden = !searchInp.hidden;
});
  searchInp.addEventListener('focusout', (e) => {
if(!e.target.value== '') {   return
}
else {
searchInp.hidden = true;

}
})
```

```html
<a class="link-secondary" href="#" aria-label="search">
     <i class="bi bi-search">123</i>
</a>
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.." hidden>
```

Comment: А в чем смысл делать этот пустой блок? ```if (! e.target.value == '') {return }```.

Comment: Чтобы не создать неудобную ситуацию для тех, кто что-то начал писать, потом тапнул мышью случайно, а инпут ищез. Можно это и не использовать. Тут уже как автор вопроса планировал.

Comment: @Макск спасибо брат, я ещё придумал кое-что, как тебе решение с mouseevents:
     
searchBtn.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    searchInp.hidden = false;
    
    searchInp.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
        searchInp.hidden = true;
    });
    
});

Comment: @ThekingArthur можно, но шевельнули мышью немного сильнее - и блок ищез. Смотрите, подходит ли вам такое по UX.

Comment: @Макск да, согласен, удобно, вот типа этого хочу.
Как думаешь, можно ли сделать так, чтобы он исчезал через минуты 2-3 или чтобы исчезал после 2-го клика по странице?

Comment: @Макск, задумку то я понял, но не понял смысла от пустого блока с ретурном.